# Why should the cosine rule be used to find an unknown in a triangle when both sine and cosine rules can be used?

Tags: trigonometry

I have been told that if the unknown of the triangle is an angle, I should use the cosine rule to avoid the ambiguous case.

Could someone explain what is this 'ambiguous case'?

An example would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the unknown angle is, say $60^\circ$, then the sine rule can't tell you that it isn't $120^\circ$ (because those two angles have the same sine value, as do all angle pairs $x$ and $180^\circ - x$). That being said, if the only thing you know is the length of two sides and one of the angles that *isn't* between them, then the sine rule is the only way to go, and the ambiguity is unavoidable.

Comment: There is only one case with probably two solutions: given two sides and the angle opposite to the shorter side. In this case only sine rule is applicable and you have to take care about the second solution.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Mathematically (as far as the sine rule is concerned), you still get two solutions if you're given the angle opposite the longer side. However, in that case, one of the solutions makes your given angle an external angle. You need to be aware of this, and know which solution to throw away.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)#Side-side-angle. How in the world can one use cosine rule in this case?!

Comment: @MichaelHoppe When did I say that you use the cosine rule in that case? I actually think I stated in the above answer 15 mins ago that "then the sine rule is the only way to go".